# How do I set an Excel RangePtr's Value = Value in C++? Currently I get HRESULT 0x80004005

Tags: c++, excel, com

I have an Excel `RangePtr` object, and I'm trying to convert its corresponding cells to values instead of formulas. I'm used to doing this in VBA where you can do this simply using `r.Value = r.Value`. In C++ I've tried an analogous approach:

```
rng->Value = rng->Value;
```

But when I run that, I get an exception from the HRESULT `0x8004005`. There's nothing within the cell values that should cause Excel to choke; the values being returned ought to be just a `_variant_t` containing a `SAFEARRAY` of `double` values. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh. Looks like `RangePtr.Value` actually has to specify a `XlRangeValueDataType` constant, which isn't present in VBA:

```
rng->Value[Excel::XlRangeValueDataType::xlRangeValueDefault] = rng->Value;
```

Or I could have used the `Value2` property instead of plain `Value`:

```
rng->Value2 = rng->Value2;
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else who has this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After painful search I came to the same conclusion, and use
value[Excel::XlRangeValueDataType::xlRangeValueDefault] to get the equivalent of range.value in c# or vb in C++/CLI. Let me see if that works... Yes, that's the solution, it works!

Btw: if you ever need to use the Range::Address property you can use the style
Address[false, false, Excel::XlReferenceStyle::xlA1, Type::Missing, Type::Missing]; with the appropriate parameters, of course.

Furthermore, regarding the value property, I found out that the presence of a cell value can be checked by:
Value[Excel::XlRangeValueDataType::xlRangeValueDefault] != nullptr

Frequently, typecasts a la "safe_cast<Excel::Range^>" and "safe_cast<Excel::Workbook^>" are also helpful. The whole subject matter of using Excel automation with C++/CLI is poorly documented.